# In R, How to manipulate character string using gsub() and perform multivariate data cleaning efficiently?

Tags: r, regex, gsub, data-science, data-cleaning

I’m rookie at R programming and I'm stuck with character string manipulation, If some one can comment with the code, I’d appreciate it. The data-frame has top Forbes’ 100 brands. I want to clean a specific column ‘Company Advertising’ as *(Check attached screenshot)*

[Forbes' Top 100 comapnies with their Advertising expenditure cloumn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n25V7.png)

- Convert all the million values into Billion as 1 M = 0.001 B
- Remove unnecessary symbols B, M and have only numerical values.

**Resulting column will look like..**
Before: 1.2 B, 2.3 B, 3 B, 808 M

After:  1.2, 2.3, 3, 0.808

Comment: Please paste the result of  `dput(d1)`, not an unusable image.

Answer (score 1):

`gsubfn` is perfect for this task:

```
library(gsubfn)
as.vector(sapply(gsubfn("[A-Z]", list(B="* 1", M= "* 1e-3"), x), 
                                      function(x) eval(parse(text=x))))
#[1] 1.200 2.500 0.808
```

#### data

```
x <- c("1.2 B", "2.5 B", "808 M")
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, can you explain this list(B="* 1", M= "* 1e-3") 
I did not get that.

Comment: @Ashish25Sahu  Here, we are creating a key/value to pair replace the 'B' with `* 1` string, 'M' with `* 1e-3` so that when when we evaluate with `eval(parse`, the other value gets multiplied with `* 1` or `* 1e-3`

Comment: This is the equivalent of the Perl construct `s/.../.../ge`.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = c("1.2 B", "2.5 B", "808 M")

y = ifelse(grepl("B",x) == T, as.numeric(gsub("\\s{1,10}B$","",x)),as.numeric(gsub("\\s{1,10}M$","",x))/1000)
View(y)


    x
1   1.200
2   2.500
3   0.808
```

Comment: `== T` is redundant at best.